# Applescript unable to grab return of Python call

Tags: python, applescript

I've used Applescript maybe 4 times in my life. And of course, I need to utilize it again for work.
My end goal is to:
•run a script that calls a python script
•save the return of the python script to a variable in A.S. (which will be 4 numbers(floats))
•pass those to Photoshop to crop images using those 4 numbers as coordinates (which come from the Python script that runs googlevision on the image to crop according to what is found in the image)

I have a working prototype in A.S. that is cropping the images in Photoshop with the coordinates, albeit hardcoded at the moment.

What I'm having issues with is saving the Python return to an A.S. variable. It's just not working. I'm starting out SUPER basic with the python script as follows:

```
def get():
    b = "5"
    return b

answer = get()
print(answer)
```

***I've tried using "Print" and just returning the information

The A.S. is as follows:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 1
    do script "cd Desktop" in window 1
    delay 1
    set myVal to do script "python test.py" in window 1
    delay 1
    display dialog myVal
end tell
```

With the code above I get the following error from A.S.

```
error "Terminal got an error: Can’t make tab 1 of window id 11768 into type string." number 
-1700 from tab 1 of window id 11768 to string
```

I've tried adding parentheses around the *do shell script* and even declaring *myVal* as a string, in which case the dialog does appear but with an empty string...

Just trying to grasp the basics of this before tackling the overall problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no need for you to be using **Terminal** when the `do shell script` *command* should suffice.

Give the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* a try:

```
set myPythonScript to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string) & "test.py"

set myVal to do shell script "python" & space & myPythonScript's quoted form

display dialog myVal
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you!

Comment: Another question - In using shell script, I'm unable to start an Anaconda Environment now. My first call was: do script "conda activate PyCloud36"
Which now gives me a 'conda command not found' error

Comment: @Michael, This has to do with the default `PATH` passed to the `do shell script` _command_, which is: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. You'll need to use a _compound command_  adding the `PATH` you want followed by a `;` and then the _command_.  You might also need to use _fully qualified pathnames_ depending on other circumstances.

Comment: @Michael, Here is one example: if I do `do shell script "brightness -l"` it returns `sh: brightness: command not found` as `brightness` is not in the default `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` _command_. However, if I do `do shell script "PATH=/Scripts:$PATH; echo $PATH"` returns: `/Scripts:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` -- On my system, if I replace `echo $PATH` with `brightness -l` it returns the output from `/Scripts/brightness` as `brightness` is in `/Scripts`.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner should do:

```
set scriptResult to (do shell script ("python /path/to/script.py")) as integer
```